# Awesomium, How can I catch the response data and change it before viewing it

Tags: awesomium

When i request a page, I need to get the returned data and changed it before viewing it
How can i do that in Awesomium?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are using Awesomium with C++ or C#.

Awesomium for C++ provides a **ResourceInterceptor** class to intercept requests and responses:

[ResourceInterceptor API for C++](http://www.awesomium.com/docs/1_7_2/cpp_api/class_awesomium_1_1_resource_interceptor.html#af31dd4e15a749eed04ba90392b9ef15c)

Unfortunately, Awesomium for C# doesn't provide the same thing. There is only an interface to catch Requests, but no equivalent for catching Responses.

[IResourceInterceptor API for C#](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/AllMembers_T_Awesomium_Core_IResourceInterceptor.htm)

Different possibilities from here:

- Tweak Awesomium for C# to implement this
- Use a 3d party tool like Fiddler to intercept and modify requests/responses

In the latter case, you can find useful resources here:

[Is it possible to intercept the content received within a wpf browser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361967/is-it-possible-to-intercept-the-content-received-within-a-wpf-browser-control)

[WPF webbrowser's LoadCompleted event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151535/wpf-webbrowsers-loadcompleted-event)

Comment: For C#: see http://pastebin.com/xegywi4w for an example IResourceInterceptor implementation .